# PHP Switch case don't work. String comparrison

Tags: php

I don't get why my switch case doesn't work.

This is my simple code:

```
public static function getToolTip(){
        $stringCode = "en";
        switch ($stringCode){
            case ("de" || "DE"):
                return self::VELOCCI_DE['tooltip'];
                break;
            case ("en" || "EN"):
                return self::VELOCCI_EN['tooltip'];
                break;
            case ("fr" || "FR"):
                return self::VELOCCI_FR['tooltip'];
                break;
            case ("es" || "ES"):
                return self::VELOCCI_ES['tooltip'];
                break;
            case ("in" || "IN"):
                return self::VELOCCI_IN['tooltip'];
                break;
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
```

It returns always the tooltip from the german constant. When I add an echo only in the first case it fires multiple times.

Comment: each of those cases resolves to true. Instead just cast the string to upper or lowercase at the top and check against one string.

Comment: This feels somewhat verbose.  Especially if you have other keys.

Comment: If you `return` from a `switch/case` then you don't need the `break;` after a `return`

Comment: what about "De" or "dE"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `("en" || "EN")` in case statement evaluates to Boolean, and in your case PHP's switch case doesn't work like this `case ('dn' || 'DN'):`

Secondly, in your code there is a `break` which is NOT reachable after the `return`, in other words you don't need to put `break` after `return` so correct code will be like this

```php
public static function getToolTip(){
    $stringCode = "en";
    switch ($stringCode){
        case 'de':
        case 'DE':
            return self::VELOCCI_DE['tooltip'];

        case 'en':
        case 'EN':
            return self::VELOCCI_EN['tooltip'];

        case 'fr':
        case 'FR':
            return self::VELOCCI_FR['tooltip'];

        case 'es':
        case 'ES':
            return self::VELOCCI_ES['tooltip'];

        case 'in':
        case 'IN':
            return self::VELOCCI_IN['tooltip'];

        default:
            return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you don't need to do this with a `switch/case` at all, you can just look-up table

Answer (score 2):

In php we using or case like this

```
           case "de":
           case "DE":
                return self::VELOCCI_DE['tooltip'];
                break;
           case "en":
           case "EN":
                return self::VELOCCI_EN['tooltip'];
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set up this method with a parameter, like this, and change the name of `$stringCode`:

```
public static function getToolTip(string $languageCode = 'EN'){
}
```

Where `$languageCode` is replacing `$stringCode = "en";` in your original method.

If you don't want a default parameter, you may set this to `null`; also to cut down the number of cases, you may test each `case` in a consistent way, like:

```
public static function getToolTip(string $languageCode = NULL){
    $languageCode = strtoupper($languageCode);
    ## Rest of your code from here
}
```

So testing using `strtoupper` will look something like:

```
public static function getToolTip(string $languageCode = 'EN'){
    switch (strtoupper($languageCode)){

        case 'DE':
            return self::VELOCCI_DE['tooltip'];

        case 'EN':
            return self::VELOCCI_EN['tooltip'];

        case 'FR':
            return self::VELOCCI_FR['tooltip'];

        case 'ES':
            return self::VELOCCI_ES['tooltip'];

        case 'IN':
            return self::VELOCCI_IN['tooltip'];

        default:
            return '';
    }
}
```

Source: [PHP: strtoupper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

Comment: +1 for casting string to uppercase. This is anyway a good advise for a lot of string comparisons where case is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Note that switch/case does loose comparison (from the manual).

`var_dump('en' == ('de' || 'DE'));` results in `bool(true)`.

So your first case always satisfies.  (Same for any string input but '0' or the empty string.)

Some kind of mapping may be easier here:

```
<?php

class Texts
{
    const VELOCCI_DE = ['tooltip' => 'Actung'];
    const VELOCCI_EN = ['tooltip' => 'Attention'];

    public static function getToolTip($code)
    {
        $code = strtolower($code);

        return [
            'de' => self::VELOCCI_DE['tooltip'],
            'en' => self::VELOCCI_EN['tooltip'],
        ][$code] ?? '';
    }
}

echo Texts::getToolTip('en');
```

Output:

```
Attention
```

However this could get unweildy very quickly.  What if you have multiple keys and translations to juggle?

Comment: I would use this method for two reasons: 1) I hate `switch/case` and 2) it leads to neater PHP scripting